# jQuery is animated on multiple elements, which is better?

Tags: jquery, animation, element, animated

I am using jQuerys animate function on a plugin, on many elements simulatensly with different durations for each element. I want to know if any animation is running or if there is no animation at all. So i came up with this:

```
if( $div1.is(':animated') || $div2.is(':animated') || $div3.is(':animated') ) return true;
else return false;
```

or this:

```
if( $div1.add($div2).add($div3).is(':animated') ) return true;
else return false;
```

Which is better???

**Do you know any other method???**

I dont want this code `$("*").is(':animated');` because it will check all animations and from other plugins animations.

Have in mind that I have many elements, not just 3.

Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could put a class on the divs you would like to check for animation?

```
if ($(".myclass").is(":animated")) return true;
```

Comment: it seems that using a class is quicker. return $(".myclass").is(":animated");

Answer (score 7):

I would go with the second as it is less code to read and think about it.

Generally, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is better.

You could also refactor that...

```
return $div1.add($div2).add($div3).is(':animated');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably keep it explicit, to save cycles. Each time you animate, increment `numberOfTotalAnimations`. In the end of animation callback, decrement it. That is if you really need speed here. Otherwise, I like @Ben's class proposal.

**UPDATE** with an example, by request:

```
var numberOfTotalAnimations = 0;

numberOfTotalAnimations++;
$('#thing').animate({
    opacity: 0.1
  }, 2000, function() {
    numberOfTotalAnimations--;
  });

if (!numberOfTotalAnimations) {
  console.log("Everything's quiet.");
} else {
  console.log("Something's moving.");
}
```

It's not pretty, it's error-prone (in that you can forget to increment or decrement the counter) - but it's fast.

Comment: Can you be more specific by giving an example?

Comment: Why not override $.fn.animate to do this 100% automatically and just check the counter. DRY + less risk.